# Header and footer with tables. Right margin go off the page

Tags: tables, margins, fancyhdr

I'm not completely sure if this topci is repeated, but anyway... I'm writing some company reports that have a special header and footer layout containing tables. I have been able to configure the layout using fancyhdr, but the tables go out of the page. Below I provide images of the desired layout and the obtained, and also the code I'm using.

Desired layout - Header
[image: Desired layout - Header]

Desired layout - Footer
[image: Desired layout - Footer]

Result - Header
[image: Result - Header]

Result - Footer
[image: Result - Footer]

As you can see, the text above the footer overlaps with the line of the table.

Finally, the code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,openany]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=28.8cm, top=3.55cm, left=2.03cm, bottom=7.28cm, right=1.27cm]{geometry}
% Title Page
\title{}
\author{}
  \setlength{\headheight}{127.69005pt}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\setlength{\footskip}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyhead[C]{%
          \begin{tabular}{|m{3.6375cm}|m{5.3475cm}|m{7.0275cm}|m{1.6875cm}|}
          \hline
           \multicolumn{4}{|m{17.66cm}|}{\centering \vspace{1.5\baselineskip}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{LOGO.png}} \\[1.23cm] \hline
          Cliente:  & REF.  & \centering Lugar: Por definir & Hoja: \\[0.77cm] \hline
           \multicolumn{3}{|m{16.10cm}|}{\centering \vspace{1.5\baselineskip} Titulo} & \multicolumn{1}{m{1.6cm}|}{Total:} \\[0.82cm] \hline
          \end{tabular}%
}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all footers
\fancyfoot[C]{%
          \begin{tabular}{|m{5.67cm}|m{5.75cm}|m{5.1cm}|m{1.52cm}|}
          \hline
      & Preparado por: & Fecha:  & Ver. \\[0.96cm] \hline 
          \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
```

What am I exactly doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Charlie

Comment: Simply resize the width of your columns.

Comment: Either you need bigger paper or smaller headers and footers.  An easy fix would be to use    \resizebox.

Comment: Aha!  The widths specified for tabular are for the text itself and does not include the spacing between columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look (explanations are below):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,openany]{report}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=28.8cm, top=3.55cm, left=2.03cm, bottom=7.28cm, right=1.27cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{helvet}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}


\setlength{\headheight}{141pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\setlength{\footskip}{22.58pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{} %% clear out all headers and footers
\fancyhead[C]{%
\begin{tabular}{
  |m{\dimexpr.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\fboxrule\relax}
  |m{\dimexpr.28\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\fboxrule\relax}
  |m{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\fboxrule\relax}
  |m{\dimexpr.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\fboxrule\relax}|
}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|m{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\fboxrule\relax}|}{%
  \centering\rule[-0.3cm]{0pt}{1cm}\raisebox{-\height}{%
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=0.7cm]{LOGO.png}}} 
\\[1.23cm] 
\hline
Cliente:  & REF.  & \centering Lugar: Por definir & Hoja: 
\\[0.77cm] 
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{
  |m{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\fboxrule\relax}|}{\centering \vspace{1.5\baselineskip} Titulo} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{m{\dimexpr.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\fboxrule\relax}|}{Total:} 
\\[0.82cm] \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \begin{tabular}{
    |m{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\fboxrule\relax}
    |m{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\fboxrule\relax}
    |m{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\fboxrule\relax}
    |m{\dimexpr.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\fboxrule\relax}|
  }
  \hline
  & Preparado por: & Fecha:  & Ver. \\[0.96cm] \hline 
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your columns width specifications had two problems:

1. You were not taking into account `\tabcolsep` (the horizontal length separating the content from the column "border") and `\fboxrule` (the thickness of the rules).
2. You were using absolute lengths, so a lot of trial-error were required and a simple change in the page layout will make you start from the beginning the calculations. Instead of this, I used fractions of `\textwidth` to calculate the widths; in this way, no matter if you change the width of the text area, the columns width will automatically accommodate to span the full text width.

I had to change the values for `\headheight` and `\footskip`; perhaps you will need to adjust thos velues depending on the actual height of the image.

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.